# Qt - catch emitted signal from multiple classes

Tags: qt, signals-slots, emit

I am developing an TCP server application. I have the newDataReceived slot and I emit a signal in it like this:

```
void myclass::newDataReceived()
{

    char data_received[1024] = {0};
    client->read(data_received, client->bytesAvailable());
    QString msg = data_received;
    QString client_ip = client->peerAddress().toString();

    emit dataReceived(msg,client_ip);
}
```

I have catched the signal from MainWindow, there is no problem. But, I have another class which is a QThread and I want this class to catch this signal too. But it does not do it. I connected the signal to my slot like,

```
srv_thread = new myclass();
connect(srv_thread, SIGNAL(dataReceived(QString,QString)), this, SLOT(incoming_message(QString,QString)));
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should only have one `myclass`.  Is that the case?  'Cause it looks like you're making a new one when you connect with the thread...

Comment: i have, myclass  MainWindow and Thread classes. myclass emits dataReceived signal. I can catch this signal from MainWindow but i could not catch it from my thread class. That is the case.

Comment: What I mean is that you should only have one instance of `myclass` - the line `xxx = new myclass();` should only appear once in your code.  Can you show where you connect that signal to `MainWindow` so I can get a better idea of what you're doing there?

Comment: Can you show the code of your `QThread` derived class ?

Comment: @XavierHolt you were right. I have been making new one. Thanks.

Comment: In this code you have at least 2 Undefined Behaviors. 1. `client->bytesAvailable()` can be larger than 1024. 2. You are assuming that you are receiving data in predefined chunks (take a look on [this answear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19682690/1387438)). 3. Your conversion to `QString` is naive and may lead to buffer overflow (you do not have warranty of null termination of buffer).