# How to read complete data in QTcpSocket?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcpsocket

Now the server (implemented with java) will send some stream data to me, my code is like below:

```
connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(read_from_server()));
```

in the `read_from_server()`:

```
{
    while (socket->bytesAvailable())
    {
        QString temp = socket->readAll();
    }
}
```

but I find that even the server sent me a string with only several characters, the data is truncated, and my function is called twice, thus `temp` is the never complete data that I want.
If server send me a longer string, my function may be called three or more times, making me diffficult to know at which time the data is transfered completely.
So anyone can tell me how to completely receive the data easily, without so many steps of bothering? I'm sorry if this is duplicated with some questions else, I couldn't get their answers work for me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you're seeing is normal for client-server communication. Data is sent in packets and the readyRead signal is informing your program that there is data available, but has no concept of what or how much data there is, so you have to handle this.

To read the data correctly, you will need a buffer, as mentioned by @ratchetfreak, to append the bytes as they're read from the stream. It is important that you know the format of the data being sent, in order to know when you have a complete message. I have previously used at least two methods to do this: -

1) Ensure that sent messages begin with the size, in bytes, of the message being sent. On receiving data, you start by reading the size and keep appending to your buffer until it totals the size to expect.

2) Send all data in a known format, such as [JSON](http://www.json.org/) or [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), which can be checked for the end of the message. For example, in the case of JSON, all packets will begin with an opening brace '{' and end with a closing brace '}', so you could count braces and match up the data, or use QJsonDocument::fromRawData to verify that the data is complete.

Having used both of these methods, I recommend using the first; include the size of a message that is being sent.

Comment: About "2", counting the braces will be a problem if the object contains strings with braces. Better try to properly parse it and assume it is not complete if it fails.

Comment: I completely agree, you would need to take that into account and be checking for strings too, though I did mention using QJsonDocument to verify the data. Thanks for highlighting this ;O)

Comment: @Merlin069 Thanks for your experience!

Comment: @TheDarkKnight If i were to send a JSON packet from PHP to a socket that is connected with a server application. Would I have to keep adding bytes to a QByteArray until a check succeeds which check if the all the bytes together equal a QJsonDocument? Ive been at this socket streaming for a few days now, and it is quite complex until you get the hang of it.

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything simple answer: Yes. However, you could send single Json objects and check for them being complete, building up the QJsonDocument with each object, but you're probably better off sticking with building up the whole document in a byte array first.

Answer (score 3):

you can use a buffer field to hold the unfinished data temporarily and handle packets as they complete:

```
{
    while (socket->bytesAvailable())
    {
        buffer.append(socket->readAll());
        int packetSize = getPacketSize(buffer);
        while(packetSize>0)
        {
            handlePacket(buffer.left(packetSize);
            buffer.remove(0,packetSize);
            packetSize = getPacketSize(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If all of the data has not yet arrived then your while loop will exit prematurely. You need to use a message format that will let the receiving code determine when the complete message has been received. For example, the message could begin with a length element, or if you are dealing with text the message could end with some character used as a terminator.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask the server to append an ending character :)

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that during tcp data transfer data are send in undefined chunks. If you are trying to read defined block size you have to know in advance expected chunk size ore have a way to determinate when your block ends (something like zero terminated c-string).

Check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19682690/1387438) doesn't help you (there is a trick to wait for expected data block).

Comment: Thanks for sharing :) like you said I'll get some way to determine when the block ends