# Lose chunk of my data when i try to send image in QByteArray via QNetworkAccessManager in json

Tags: qt, qtnetwork

I compared the data i send and recieve and it is turned out that the end of my data, which i recieve on my server is cut, is QNetworkmanager has a request lenght limit?

photo struct.

```
typedef struct Photo_{
    std::string name;
    int likes;
    int comments;
    int id;
    int user_id;
QByteArray img_in_bytes;
}photo;
```

Here is the function that convert data to json and send it to server.

```cpp
void MainWindow::send_new_photo_to_server(photo item){
    QJsonDocument doc;

    QNetworkRequest req(url);

    qDebug() << QString::number(item.likes);
    qDebug() << QString::number(item.comments);
    qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(item.name);

    req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "text");
    req.setRawHeader("request-type", "addMainEntity");

    QBuffer buf(&item.img_in_bytes);
    QByteArray img_in_bytes = buf.data().toBase64();

    QJsonObject object;

    object.insert("comments", QString::number(item.comments));
    object.insert("img_in_bytes",QLatin1String(img_in_bytes));
    object.insert("name", QString::fromStdString(item.name));
    object.insert("likes", QString::number(item.likes));

    doc.setObject(object);

    qDebug() << doc.toJson();

    manager->post(req, doc.toJson());

    qDebug() << "here you are";
}
```

There is function that handle a request. It`s no need in upload procces function becouse data has already been currupted by the time it is called.

```cpp
void Server::get_request(){

    i++;
    qDebug() << i << "\n";

    QTcpSocket* socket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());

    QString data = socket->readAll();

    socket->waitForBytesWritten(3000);
    qDebug() << "Recieved data: \n" << data;

    this->process_request(data);
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce your server to analyze where the problem is?

Comment: I think the problem isn`t with server, becouse other requests work fine, but i will post a server request proccesing

Comment: My idea is to be able to analyze your code and see where the problem is, for example using wireshark

Comment: It will be a problem to share the whole way of the date becouse it is in 4-5 different files, but i am sure that it is valid by the moment i send it.

Comment: What `socket->waitForBytesWritten(3000);` returns?

Comment: 130-150 kb  approximately

Comment: @vahancho bool.

Comment: @ShyEnough, I asked about a value, not the return type. Can you print it out?

Comment: @vahancho false

Comment: @ShyEnough, isn't it the indication that something goes wrong? Did you try to increase the timeout?

Comment: @vahancho tried to set waitForBytesWritten argument to max , but it didn`t work.

Comment: Why are you even calling `waitForBytesWritten`? I don't see anything being written to the socket.

Comment: @thuga it was a mistake i already replaced it with waitForReadyRead

Comment: How is `Server::get_request()` called? Do you just connect the `readyRead` signal of the `QTcpSocket` to it?

Comment: @thuga yes it is just a slot connected to readyRead

Comment: As you noticed, stream protocols receive data in packets rather than the whole data at once. It is up to you to determine when the whole data has arrived. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288282/how-to-read-complete-data-in-qtcpsocket).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem but it will work only for transferring data in json.
Here is the loop which read all chunks of the data.

Data is a QByteArray which contains data send by client.
As you know Json ends with '}' , so i read data from socket until i get the the last chunk of data with '}' in the end.

I know it is very bad practice but it is the only thing that worked out.

Write me back if you find better solution.

```
Data =  "";
while(!Data.contains("}")){
    socket->waitForReadyRead();
    Data += socket->readAll();
}
```