# How to listen on already connected QTcpSocket

Tags: qt

On client side, I have socket, which is connected to QTcpServer. I want to make a QtcpServer on client side, which listen on same socket. I tried this.

```
QTcpSocket *tcpSocket=new QTcpSocket(this); //connected socket.
QTcpServer *tcpServer=new QTcpServer(this);
tcpSocket->bind(QAbstractSocket::ReuseAddressHint);
tcpServer->setSocketDescriptor(tcpSocket->socketDescriptor());
```

tcpServer is listening on same socket but other client failed to connect to this tcpServer;
Socket Operation time out msg is displayed.
What is suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

`QTcpSocket` inherits `QIODevice` so connect to signal [readyRead()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qiodevice.html#readyRead).
Keep in mind [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19682690/1387438).

Comment: I want to listen on port, on which tcpSocket is connected. That's my question, how to do it?

Comment: what are you saying is incoherent, but check this http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#listen