# read and write to qtcpsocket using qdatastream

Tags: qt, sockets, network-programming, qtcpsocket

There are various methods of reading and writing from a [QTcpSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html) using a [QDatastream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html) as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681564/read-from-qtcpsocket-using-qdatastream)

The difference is, I will be sending more than "one packet" or blocks.

*A basic implementation on the server (sending) side and client (recieving) is seen below - only the actual sending and receiving snippets are shown*

**More Info, What I tried:**

When writing to a QTcpSocket, I attempted to use the `QTcpSocket::canReadLine()` however this fails straightup after the `QTcpSocket::waitForReadReady()` signal fires.

I then tried `QDataStream::atEnd()` in a while loop which causes a system crash :(

The code below shows my latest attempt of going through the QDataStream docs, and utilzing the commitTransaction where it states

> If no full packet is received, this code restores the stream to the initial position, after which you need to wait for more data to arrive.

Under the heading `Using Read Transactions`. But ofcourse, this just reads one block that is sent, i.e the first block.

**Question:**

When writing to a `QTcpSocket` multiple times, and flushing the socket each time to send that data, how can I read this from a `QTcpSocket` as it is send, keep the original "send structure"?

The example below only reads the first block and ends. I would like to read the block containing "Response 2" and "Response 3".

**Code Implementations:**

//server.h

```
//...
QTcpSocket *clientSocket = nullptr;
QDataStream in;
//...
```

//server.cpp

```
//...
in.setDevice(clientSocket);
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);

in.startTransaction();

QString nextFortune;
in >> nextFortune;

if (in.commitTransaction())
    ui->lblOut->setText(nextFortune);

if (clientSocket != nullptr) {
    if (!clientSocket->isValid()) {
        qDebug() << "tcp socket invalid";
        return;
    }
    if (!clientSocket->isOpen()) {
        qDebug() << "tcp socket not open";
        return;
    }

    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);

    out << QString(QString("Response:") + nextFortune);
    if (!clientSocket->write(block)){
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Server"),tr("Could not send message"));
    }
    clientSocket->flush();
//        block.clear();

    out << QString("Response number 2");
    if (!clientSocket->write(block)){
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Server"),tr("Could not send message"));
    }
    clientSocket->flush();
//        block.clear();

    out << QString("Response number 3 here, and this is the end!");
    if (!clientSocket->write(block)){
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Server"),tr("Could not send message"));
    }
    clientSocket->flush();
    clientSocket->disconnectFromHost();

}
//...
```

And the client side

//client.h

```
//...
QTcpSocket *tcp_con = nullptr;
QDataStream in;
//...
```

//client.cpp

```
//...
if(!tcp_con->waitForReadyRead()){
    qDebug(log_lib_netman_err) << "tcp con timeout for reading";
    tcp_con->disconnectFromHost();
    return ReturnObject(ReturnCode::SocketError, QString());
}

in.setDevice(tcp_con);
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);

in.startTransaction();

QList<QString> data_rcv = QList<QString>();
QString s;

//    while (tcp_con->canReadLine()) {
//        in >> s;
//        data_rcv.push_back(s);
//    }
//    while (!in.read) {
in >> s;
data_rcv.push_back(s);
//    }


while (!in.commitTransaction()){
    qDebug(log_lib_netman_info) << "waiting for more data";
    in >> s;
    data_rcv.push_back(s);
    //        qDebug(log_lib_netman_err) << "Unable to send data to server";
    //        tcp_con->disconnectFromHost();
    //        return ReturnObject(ReturnCode::FailedReceiving, QString());
}

//    if (s.isEmpty()) {
//        qDebug(log_lib_netman_err) << "Empty response recieved";
//        tcp_con->disconnectFromHost();
//        return ReturnObject(ReturnCode::NoDataRecieved, QString());
//    }

tcp_con->disconnectFromHost();
return ReturnObject(ReturnCode::ReceivedSuccess, data_rcv);
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This should be useful [Fortune Client Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneclient-example.html)

Comment: @VladimirBershov Hi, this is based on the fortune client server, i created an example of my own, extracting the relevant code for sending and recieving. From this, I implemented it into my current application. the fortune client/server example only sends one "message"/block. My question relates to, how am I able to loop over a list, writing to the socket on each loop iteration and read this from the client side, as it is sent. As seen in the above code, I attempted this without success (client.cpp)