# How to use standardised request response transactions using QTcp?

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I'm making a server-client system for **a client placed within a loop to continuously query a predetermined set of information from a server**. I've cooked up a bit of code from what I could understand about how the TCP implementation of the Qt framework works but I'm not sure if what I have written is the right way to do it.

---

At first, I made an enum with a bunch of `QByteArray` variables in the client QTcp class to pass as a query from the client side to the server as shown below

```cpp
enum datamap
{
    QByteArray data1 = 1;
    QByteArray data2 = 2;
    QByteArray data3 = 3;
    // and so on...
};
```

Then I make the function that takes in an enum `datamap` variable to pass to the server and a variable to hold the current request(to avoid mixup between data received for the wrong request) as shown below

```cpp
datamap current_request = 0;
int client::setDataToGet(datamap& data)
{
    if(socket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
    {
        current_request = data;
        socket->write(data);
        return socket->waitForBytesWritten();
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

After this, I create the `readyRead()` slot that connects to the `readyread` signal to handle responses from the server and send to functions that will display the received data in the respective text box based on the `current_request` variable as shown below

```cpp
void client::readyRead()
{
    QTcpSocket *m_socket = static_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
    while(m_socket->bytesAvailable() > 0)
    {
        QByteArray buf = socket->readAll();
    }
    switch(current_request):
    case 1:
        dispToTextBox1(buf);
    case 2:
        dispToTextBox2(buf);
    case 3:
        dispToTextBox3(buf);
    // and so on....
}
```

---

Now, for the server side, I make the `readyRead()` slot that connects to the `readyread()` signal from a socket listener called in the `newConnection()` function.

This takes in the handle from the client and accordingly is supposed to return back data associated with the handle. The code for the slot is as follows

```cpp
void server::readyRead()
{
    QTcpSocket *m_socket = static_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
    while(m_socket->bytesAvailable() > 0)
    {
        QByteArray buf = m_socket->readAll();
    }
    switch(buf):
    case 1:
        data = collectDatafromStream1();
        m_socket->write(data); m_socket->flush();
    case 2:
        data = collectDatafromStream2();
        m_socket->write(data); m_socket->flush();
    case 3:
        data = collectDatafromStream3();
        m_socket->write(data); m_socket->flush();
    //and so on.....    
}
```

---

Could someone please verify if this is the right way to do this or if there is a better alternative for handling the task.

Comment: "QByteArray data1 = 1;
    QByteArray data2 = 2;
    QByteArray data3 = 3;
    // and so on..." - without looking at anything else; that's clearly bonkers. Why don't you use a container?

Comment: If you app has GUI, do not use waitForXxx methods. Use signals and slots instead. Also, in GUI programs, you can't have a loop doing something continuously, you have to use something like QTimer to do things at certain intervals (incuding interval 0 for "as fast as possible"), or preferably have things happen as result of something else happening (such as reacting to data received from network, or using doing something in the GUI). Use signals and slots.

Comment: I plan on using QHash for the functional working version. As for now, to contain the possible errors from the working concept, I have used an enum to represent the flow.

Comment: ok. I then use the signals and slots instead of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Got the concept model to work with a few changes. Used the response given by "sashoalm" in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681564/read-from-qtcpsocket-using-qdatastream) question to pass the data using QdataStream and used signals & slots to cycle through the read-write sequence for each request type.

---

my server class is as follows

tcpserver.h

```cpp
#ifndef TCPSERVER_H
#define TCPSERVER_H

#include<qt5/QtNetwork/QTcpServer>
#include<qt5/QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>
#include<qt5/QtCore/QObject>

class TCPServer : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit TCPServer(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void dataReceived(QByteArray);

private slots:
    void newConnection();
    void disconnected();
    void readyRead();

private:
    QTcpServer *server;
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    QHash<QString, int> reverse_hash;

};

#endif // TCPSERVER_H
```

tcpserver.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "tcpserver.h"
#include <qt5/QtCore/QDataStream>
#include <qt5/QtCore/QBuffer>
#include <qt5/QtCore/QString>

class BlockWriter
{
public:
    BlockWriter(QIODevice *io)
    {
        buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        this->io = io;
        _stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);
        _stream.setDevice(&buffer);
        _stream << quint64(0);
    }

    ~BlockWriter()
    {
        _stream.device()->seek(0);
        _stream << static_cast<quint64>(buffer.size());

        io->write(buffer.buffer());
    }

    QDataStream &stream()
    {
        return _stream;
    }

private:
    QBuffer buffer;
    QDataStream _stream;
    QIODevice *io;
};


class BlockReader
{
public:
    BlockReader(QIODevice *io)
    {
        buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
        _stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);
        _stream.setDevice(&buffer);

        qint64 blockSize;

        readMax(io, sizeof(blockSize));
        buffer.seek(0);
        _stream >> blockSize;

        readMax(io, blockSize);
        buffer.seek(sizeof(blockSize));
    }

    QDataStream& stream()
    {
        return _stream;
    }

private:
    void readMax(QIODevice *io, qint64 n)
    {
        while (buffer.size() < n) {
            buffer.write(io->read(n - buffer.size()));
        }
    }

    QBuffer buffer;
    QDataStream _stream;
};

TCPServer::TCPServer(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    server = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), SLOT(newConnection()));
    qDebug() << "Listening:" << server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 5404);

    reverse_hash.insert("data1", 1);
    reverse_hash.insert("data2", 2);

}

void TCPServer::newConnection()
{
    while (server->hasPendingConnections())
    {
        qDebug()<<"incoming connection!";
        socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
        connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(readyRead()));
        connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), SLOT(disconnected()));
    }
}

void TCPServer::disconnected()
{
    qDebug() << "disconnected!";
    disconnect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()));
    disconnect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()));
    socket->deleteLater();
}

void TCPServer::readyRead()
{
    qDebug() << "Read!";
    QString data;
    BlockReader(socket).stream() >> data;
    qDebug() <<"received data request: " << data;

    switch(reverse_hash.value(data))
    {
    case 1: //call sequence to respond to request.(write to data)
        qDebug() << "responding go data1 request!";
        break;
    case 2://call sequence to respond to request.(write to data)
        qDebug() << "responding go data2 request!";
        break;

    }

    BlockWriter(socket).stream()<<data;
    socket->flush();

}
```

---

my client GUI class is as follows

mainwindow.h

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtNetwork>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    QHash<int, QString> hash;
    int current_slot, starting_slot, ending_slot;

signals:
    void dataSet();

public slots:
    void connectToHost();
    void connected();
    void disconnected();
    void setDatatoGet();
    void getData();
    //bool writeData(QByteArray data);

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>

class BlockWriter
{
public:
    BlockWriter(QIODevice *io)
    {
        buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        this->io = io;
        _stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);
        _stream.setDevice(&buffer);
        _stream << quint64(0);
    }

    ~BlockWriter()
    {
        _stream.device()->seek(0);
        _stream << static_cast<quint64>(buffer.size());
        io->write(buffer.buffer());
    }

    QDataStream &stream()
    {
        return _stream;
    }

private:
    QBuffer buffer;
    QDataStream _stream;
    QIODevice *io;
};


class BlockReader
{
public:
    BlockReader(QIODevice *io)
    {
        buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
        _stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);
        _stream.setDevice(&buffer);

        qint64 blockSize;
        readMax(io, sizeof(blockSize));
        buffer.seek(0);
        _stream >> blockSize;
        readMax(io, blockSize);
        buffer.seek(sizeof(blockSize));
    }

    QDataStream& stream()
    {
        return _stream;
    }

private:
    void readMax(QIODevice *io, qint64 n)
    {
        while (buffer.size() < n) {
            buffer.write(io->read(n - buffer.size()));
        }
    }
    QBuffer buffer;
    QDataStream _stream;
};


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    starting_slot = 1;
    current_slot = starting_slot;
    ending_slot = 2;


    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->status_label->setStyleSheet("background-color:red;");
    ui->receive_btn->setEnabled(false);

    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connectToHost();

    connect(ui->conn_btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(connectToHost()));
    connect(ui->receive_btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setDatatoGet()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(dataSet()), this , SLOT(setDatatoGet()));


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::connectToHost()
{
    socket->deleteLater();
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->connectToHost(QHostAddress("192.168.0.127"), 5404);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connected()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));

    //ADD to hash table
    hash.insert(1, "data1");
    hash.insert(2, "data2");

}

void MainWindow::connected()
{
    ui->status_label->setStyleSheet("background-color:green;");
    ui->receive_btn->setEnabled(true);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(getData()));

}

void MainWindow::disconnected()
{
    ui->status_label->setStyleSheet("background-color:red;");
    ui->receive_btn->setEnabled(false);
    disconnect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(getData()));

}

void MainWindow::setDatatoGet()
{

    if(current_slot == ending_slot + 1)
    {
        current_slot = starting_slot;
    }

    qDebug() <<"calling request data slot " << current_slot;


    BlockWriter(socket).stream() << hash.value(current_slot);

    socket->flush();
    current_slot++;

}

void MainWindow::getData()
{
    QString data;
    BlockReader(socket).stream() >> data;
    //qDebug() <<"received response, current received data is for slot "<< data <<"and current number is" << current_slot;
    switch (current_slot - 1)
    {
    case 1:
        //display in respective label
        qDebug() << "display data1 to label!";
        break;
    case 2:
        //display in respective label
        qDebug() << "display data2 to label!";
        break;
    }

    emit dataSet();
}
```